# IllegalStateException when starting MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i am streaming data (distance) in arduino with an ultrasonic sensor and i want to create a beeping sound that will change its speed depending on the value of the distance.so i have this in my `beginListenForData()` method.

```
public void beginListenForData() {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
        Looper.prepare();
    }
    final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    try {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler1.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {

                                            incomingData = data.trim();
                                            distance = Integer.parseInt(incomingData);
                                            lastDist = distance;
                                            tvResults.setText(incomingData);
                                            /*if (distance<=80 && lastDist > 80) {
                                                swipescreen.release();
                                                warning.start();
                                                warning.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                                        warning.release();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                                entered = true;
                                            }*/

                                            if (distance <= 70 && distance > 60) {
                                                fifty.release();
                                                sixty.start();
                                                sixty.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                                        sixty.start();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                            if (distance <= 60 && distance > 50) {
                                                sixty.release();
                                                forty.release();
                                                fifty.start();
                                                fifty.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                                        fifty.start();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                            /*
                                            if (distance <= 50 && distance > 40) {
                                                fifty.release();
                                                forty.start();
                                                thirty.release();
                                            }
                                            if (distance <= 40 && distance > 30) {
                                                forty.release();
                                                thirty.start();
                                                twenty.release();

                                            }
                                            if (distance <= 30 && distance > 20) {

                                                fifteen.release();
                                                twenty.start();
                                                thirty.release();
                                            }
                                            if (distance <= 20 && distance > 10) {

                                                ten.release();
                                                fifteen.start();
                                                twenty.release();

                                            }

                                            if (distance <= 10 && distance > 5) {
                                                five.release();
                                                ten.start();
                                                fifteen.release();

                                            }
                                            if (distance <= 5) {
                                                five.start();
                                                ten.release();
                                            }*/

                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException e) {}
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    workerThread.start();
    //return incomingData;
}
```

when i try this code, the beep will start when the distance drops to below 70 but when it reaches below 60 it will give an IllegalStateException error, what am i doing wrong?

---

### LogCat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.notifyActionMetaChange(MediaPlayer.java:2734)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1079)
at com.ardudroid.projects.ultrasoundbelt.MainActivity$38$1.run(MainActivity.java:1476)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`(MainActivity.java:1476)` is this `fifty.start();`

Comment: The stacktrace might shed some light on it.

Comment: I suspect that either the `sixty` mediaplayer is still playing, so you need to stop it first before you can release it. Or `forty` isn't started/prepared yet. But as @GeraldSchneider said a stacktrace would be useful here.

Comment: ok ok please check the logcat, i edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `fifty.release()`, You cannot use the `fifty mediaplayer` again. `Release` means, the `mediaPlayer object` is not longer valid. From the docs:

**After release(), the object is no longer available.**

You are releasing the `fifty mediaplayer object` if You are under 70, then it reaches the value under 60 and You start it again. You have to be sure to initialize the media player again in that state before calling `start()`.

for example:

release the media player object:

```
private void releaseFifty(){
fifty.release();
fifty = null;
}
```

init before using it again:

```
private void initAndStartFifty(){
fifty = MediaPlayer.create(activity.this, R.raw.yourRecord);
fifty.start(); 
}
```

Comment: Your welcome....there are some more things to be aware of. You should read the documentation for MediaPlayer here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: i also see alot of ways to loop the music, is what im doing wrong? also in the initialization, should i practice using `.setDataSource(context, mediaUri)`?

Comment: I can´t see how You have implemented this, but it doesn´t matter. it makes no difference if You initialize it by MediaPlayer.create() method or by setting resource like You did. In fact, if You call the create() method, the mediaPlayer is in the prepared state and You don´t need to call it extra. Initailizing like You did, needs only some steps more. So, You did it the right way, I guess.

Comment: and if You want to loop You should make sure to follow the guidelines. I think Your way works, but it´s better to make it like they show.